# file command gives incorrect encoding type

Tags: csv, character-encoding, unicode, ascii

I have a csv file in hand. When I ran 'file -i filename', it shows that it's encoded as `us-ascii`. But when I ran `cat filename | csvcut -t -e us-ascii`, I got an error:

"Your file is not "us-ascii" encoded. Please specify the correct encoding with the -e flag or with the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable"

[csvkit documentation can be found here.](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/)

I also found the file has HEX codes like 0xd1, which caused some issues. So how do I find the correct encoding of this file? Ideally I would like to convert it to utf-8 encoding. What shall  do?

Comment: For example include a part of your txt file in your question.

Comment: EBCDIC ?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/r_deeadvrf_EBCDIC_to_ASCII.html

Comment: Hi @IporSircer, to prepare the example file, I took a small part of the file out and made sure it contains the row of 0xd1 which caused trouble. Then I re-ran the `file -i` command and this time it says the encoding is iso-8559-1. And that seems to be the correct encoding for the original file. So I guess the `file -i` only looks at a portion of a file and draws a conclusion?

Comment: Bottom line? Determining the correct encoding of a file is actually very, very difficult, unfortunately.If Python is an option, you can try `chardet` which gives great results in my opinion. FYI even chardet will give you results with a _confidence interval_ (which is pretty smart!). https://pypi.org/project/chardet/

Comment: Please, could you share the file?